# swift: How to have same closure to be executed from two separate methods

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a situation where I have function say

```
func openViewController(completion:(success:Bool) -> Void)
{

   //code here to present some view controller name MYVC 
   self.presentViewController(myVC, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}
```

From MYVC I get call back with help of delegate in below function in same class as I called above method of openViewController

```
 func handleDismissOfVC(){

     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{
     })
 }
```

Now the challenge for me is to call completion block of openViewController of with success flag when I dismiss the view controller with handleDimissOfVC(). How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want to do `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{ openViewController(){ flag in } })`? Did you try it?

Comment: This would call the openViewController() again and execute its code. I want the completion block of openViewController() to be called which will eventually take me back to caller of openVewController()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance variable to hold the closure. in openViewController, save the closure to that instance variable.

In your handleDismissOfVC function, invoke the block that was saved to the instance variable.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to provide the completion block to MyVC as a property, like this:

```
class MyVC {
    // Completion callback for when this VC is dismissed.
    var complete: ((success: Bool) -> Void)?

    func dismiss() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{
            if let c = complete {
                c(success: true)
            }
        })
    }
}

func openViewController(completion:(success:Bool) -> Void) {

    // Pass the completion block to the VC.
    myVC.complete = completion
    self.presentViewController(myVC, animated: true, completion: {
    })
}
```

I think something like that should do it. Although, this looks like it may be a better fit for the delegate pattern, depending on where the original block is originating from.